# Is it possible to use the Mercurial Fetch extension with the TortoiseHg merge dialog?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm trying to implement Mercurial in the company where I work. Previously we used ClearCase, but for various reasons we decided to upgrade to Mercurial. The development team is very accustomed to the ClearCase workflow, especially the visual tools. Therefore, for our implementation of Mercurial, we will be using TortoiseHg.

A Mercurial extension that caught my attention is the Fetch extension, which allows to do a "hg pull -u" followed by "hg merge" and "hg commit", if necessary. The extension basically does what we want and integrates perfectly with TortoiseHg configuring it to run automatically "Post Pull."

The only problem is that the Fetch extension does not allow to compile and test the merge before running the commit. However, using the TortoiseHg merge dialog with "hgtk merge -r tip" there is a visual way to run the merge command, but with the advantage of allowing me to compile and run the tests. If all went well I press the Commit button, but if something went wrong just press Undo and everything is back as before.

TortoiseHg Merge Dialog: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a2f43fe5ff.png

So, my question is: 
**Is it possible to use the Mercurial Fetch extension with the TortoiseHg merge dialog?**

If it's not possible, how would you recommend implementing this workflow? Is there a way to assign an Alias to this secuence:

```
hg pull -u
* if merge is needed *
   hgtk merge -r tip
```

I am not sure if you could have an "if" in an alias, but I think not.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question: no, there are no way to make such aliases with the command line version of Mercurial or with TortoiseHg.